# how to make one items position equal to another items height in interface builder using autolayout?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, xcode6

Is there a way to create the following autolayout constraint purely in interface builder?

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multipler:0.25 constant:0.0]
```

I am trying to position view1 1/4 of the way down from the top edge of view2

Comment: Found an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Press Option (alt) and drag from one view to another view .
[image]

You have to select "Equal Heights"...

and then change the mutlipier to 0.25 as you mentioned in the question.
[image]

Comment: This answers how to set up a relationship where one item's height is related to another item's heights. What I am actually looking for is how to make one item's position related to another item's height.